# Cannot call DllImport in web api netcore hosted as windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, dllimport, webapi

- The dll if they are in bin /
- Also, this application works correctly with the console
- I am using netcore 2.2
- Class dll import

```
    public class SDK
    {
        public const int POSITION_TOP_LEFT =      0;
        public const int POSITION_TOP =           1;
        public const int POSITION_TOP_RIGHT =     2;
        public const int POSITION_RIGHT =         3;
        public const int POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT =  4;
        public const int POSITION_BOTTOM =        5;
        public const int POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT =   6;
        public const int POSITION_LEFT =          7;
        public const int POSITION_CENTER =        8;
    
        public const int WEBCAM_VIEW_PADDING =    0;
        public const int WEBCAM_VIEW_CROPPING =   1;
        public const int WEBCAM_VIEW_STRETCHING = 2;
    
        [DllImport("ScnLib.dll")] public static extern void ScnLib_About();
        [DllImport("ScnLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern bool ScnLib_SetLicenseW(string Name, string Email, string Key);
        [DllImport("ScnLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern void ScnLib_GetErrorMessageW(StringBuilder ErrMsg); // ErrMsg >= 2048 Chars
        [DllImport("ScnLib.dll")] public static extern bool ScnLib_CheckComponents();
        [DllImport("ScnLib.dll")] public static extern bool ScnLib_Initialize();
        [DllImport("ScnLib.dll")] public static extern void ScnLib_Uninitialize(); }
```

- Web Api Endpoint

```
       [HttpGet("start")]
        public IActionResult start()
        {            
            try
            {  
                
                bool test = ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_IsRecording(); 
                log.Debug("seguimiento 0_ = " + test);
    
                if (ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_IsRecording())
                {
                    log.Warn("Grabación activa.");
                    return BadRequest("Grabación activa.");
                }
    
                log.Debug("seguimiento 00_");
                bool test2 = ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_Initialize();
                log.Debug("seguimiento 000_");
                ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_SetLicenseW("example", "example", "example");
                ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_SetVideoBitrate(720);
                ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_SetLogoImageW("logo.png");
    
                log.Debug("seguimiento 1_");
    
                ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_SetLogoPosition(ZDSoft.SDK.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT, 0, 0);
                if (!ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_IsRecordAudioSource(false))
                {
                    ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_RecordAudioSource(false, true);
                }
    
                log.Debug("seguimiento 2_");
    
                var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), 
                "Recording", $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.mp4");           
    
                ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_SetVideoPathW(path);
    
                log.Debug("seguimiento 3_");
    
                ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_StartRecording();
    
                log.Debug("seguimiento 4_");
    
                log.Info("Grabacion en Progreceso...");                
    
                return Ok("Grabacion en Progreceso...");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

- The tracking of the log is that in this line

`bool test2 = ZDSoft.SDK.ScnLib_Initialize();`

I have been looking for an answer, I have seen that it could be a matter of permissions but if so, because when running the application in visual studio I have a correct functioning and even when doing the build

Comment: Is there any error message? As you said, perhaps the issue relates the permission or the DLL file missing after deploy, so, try to capture the detailed error message.

Comment: I don't have an error message, it just keeps loading and doesn't do more, I even have a windows event log and no error log.

Comment: I had read that it was due to the type of session that the service had since this dll is for screen recording but I have even seen that there is no service with session 0 but there are still applications that do the same but I do not know how to do it if is that that was the solution.

Comment: Also if I call another function of the dll it responds well, but coincidentally this function does not call the recording if not a status, this makes me think that if it is a problem with the recording in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Please Run Service with administrator privileges.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).